# Can't activate Mamba env in PowerShell Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, conda, mamba

1. Add new Profile in Windows Terminal
2. Use the following execution string

code:

```
pwsh.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mambaforge\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mambaforge'"
```

3. Base environment will be active, but can't switch to a newly created environment, no error message. Simply it stays at (base)

How to do this for Mamba on Windows 11 using Windows Terminal and PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1717) github issue, the mamba installation on windows isn't properly handling the mamba-alias for windows 10/11 using powershell / powershell 7+.

You can add a mamba alias manually following the steps:

1. Copy and rename `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mambaforge\shell\condabin\mamba-hook.ps1` to `conda-hook.ps1`

   - Copy the line: `$Env:CONDA_EXE` change it to: `$Env:MAMBA_EXE` and `conda.exe` to `mamba.exe`
   - In the Import-Module line change `Conda.psm1` to `Mamba.psm1`
2. Copy and rename `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mambaforge\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1` to `Mamba.psm1`

   - Under "CONDA WRAPPER" section in the middle, copy-paste the entirety of function `Invoke-Conda()`, rename the copy function `Invoke-Mamba()`, and change `$Env:CONDA_EXE` to `$Env:MAMBA_EXE`. It appears in two places!
   - Under "ALIASES" section near the bottom, add New-Alias `mamba Invoke-Mamba -Force`
   - Under "EXPORTS" section at the end, add `Invoke-Mamba` to the list after `Invoke-Conda` (mind the backticks)
3. Create a shortcut on your desktop or a new Terminal Profile pointing to:

   `pwsh -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mambaforge\shell\condabin\mamba-hook.ps1' ; conda activate '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\mambaforge' "`
4. Run it and you have all mamba commands working!

Answer (score -1):

I was confused by all the different answers out there too, but finally got this work on windows 10:

```
pwsh -NoExit -Command "& conda activate mamba_env_name"
```

Where mamba_env_name is the name of the environment you want to activate

Comment: I already have this added to the Windows Terminal Profile to be in (base), but it doesn't solve the problem that `mamba activate xxx` does nothing and you're still in (base) instead of xxx.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to Jon's answer, you can just directly use conda instead.

P.S, make sure that you initialize on PowerShell:
`mamba init powershell`

And then activate it:
`conda activate`

Note: this will activate the base env, so you'll need to append your env

This worked for me on PowerShell 7.3.6

Comment: On my machine, `mamba init powershell` doesn't solve the issue, that `mamba activate xxx` doesn't work.